# AngularJS $http returns status code 0 from failed CORS request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, cors

Okay, I've looked all over for this.  Basically we're using $http request that ARE cross domain requests.  Our server allows the domain and when a request returns 200, everything is OK.  However, anytime our server returns an error, 500, 401, whatever, Angular thinks it's a CORS issue.

I debugged the response with Fiddler to verify my server IS returning a 500, yet Angular chokes on it.

Here's the request:

```
       var params = {
            url: "fakehost/example",
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic encodedAuthExample"
            }
        };

       $http(params).then(
            function (response) { // success 

            },
            function (error) { // error 
                 // error.status is always 0, never includes data error msg
            });
```

Then in the console, I will see this:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load fakehost/example. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'mylocalhost:5750' is therefore not allowed access.

Yet, in fiddler, the true response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 26 Aug 2014 12:18:17 GMT
Content-Length: 5683

{"errorId":null,"errorMessage":"Index was outside the bounds of the array.","errorDescription":"Stack trace here"}
```

I'm on AngularJS v1.2.16

Comment: Just to confirm, the error.data property is undefined?

Comment: not undefined, but the entire response in the responseError interceptor is:

Object {data: "", status: 0, headers: function, config: Object, statusText: ""}

Comment: Also, if I purposely send a failed authorization, the status code and data returns properly, so it has to be some combo of the 500 error and CORS request:

{data: Object, status: 401, headers: function, config: Object, statusText: "Unauthorized"}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I found an answer, looks like you will have to inject in your asp.net pipeline the correct CORS headers, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3336).

Comment: Ah you're the man/woman.  This is jogging my memory now, I think we implemented this at once and it was lost.  Thank you, very much.

Comment: I also ended up here when using OAuth. I thought I've nothing to do with CORS
but when the user logged out and my page with JS was still served from the browser cache,
it was the first XHR that received the 302. I planned to handle it, but it turned out that Angular followed it to login page
of the OAuth provider, this became a cross-site request (rightly disallowed)
and surprised me with status = 0 in the error handler.

Comment: @acg i have no control of server code to change the response headers.is there any way to make angular aware of the real status code in this case

Comment: i have posted a new question in this regard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312703/whenever-a-cors-http-request-fails-the-response-returned-is-always-0