# Whenever a CORS $http request fails, the response returned is always 0

Tags: angularjs, http-status-code-503

this is a similar question to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506165/angularjs-http-returns-status-code-0-from-failed-cors-request) in SO.But the answer provided here cannot be applied in my case as i cannot change the response headers from server.

Suppose an http POST to a different origin. This implies CORS, including a CORS preflight exchange. Now suppose the OPTIONS request returns a `503 service unavailable`  error due to a server problem. In this case the error handler gives `""`for data and `0` for status instead of giving me the status code 503 and the text:`service not available`. An example of this scenario is illustrated in the below image.

[image]

[image]

I am using angularjs $http and i know in the response there are no CORS header if such errors happen.and i cannot change it.

Is there any way i can receive the proper error code and the text in my rejection object.

Comment: I may be asking the obvious, but if you can't change the server and you know it doesn't have CORS headers, then why would you even attempt to make a cross site request in the first place?

Comment: @Claies thank you for your time! The server sends CORS Headers for all the successful requests.But when error like `503-service unavailable` happens it simply do not send the CORS Headers which i do not have control over.

Comment: hmm I've never encountered that sort of issue before, but I'll do a bit of research on it and see what I can dig up.

Comment: I am also trying to dig in to this and see why angular is converting the real status code to 0.

Comment: @Claies is this response headers the only reason to get status code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not an issue of AngularJS / $http but it is the behavior of the browsers and their XMLHttpRequest object: If the CORS request fails, the browser does not give any information back to the caller.

Before I got this understanding, I also though it to be an AngularJS issue and I raised an open issue on github of Angular -> with the corresponding comment.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13085#issuecomment-148047721

So I think there seems no other way to solve this as to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header also on the proxy / load balancer in case of 503.

**Edit:**
If your load balancer is a HAproxy, the following may help you too:
[HAproxy: different 503 errorfile for OPTIONS and POST methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022378/haproxy-different-503-errorfile-for-options-and-post-methods/34071533#34071533)
It shows how to let HAproxy anwer the CORS requests autonomous.