# Error handling for 503 status code through promise in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I want to display some message if the login API call gives 503 status code. Below is my code for that -

```
function authenticate(user) {
        var req = {
            method: "POST",
            url: baseurl + "login",
            data: data
        };


            return $http(req).then(function(response) {

                    if (response.data.access_token) {
                        setUserInfo(user, response.data.access_token);
                        return response.data;
                    } else {
                        return $q.reject({});
                    }

                }).catch(function(error) {
                    return $q.reject(error);
                });                    

    }`
```

The problem is that the error object(inside catch block) is showing "-1" for status instead of showing it as "503", but in the network console of browser, I can see 503 status for the login API call. I am not able to understand, what I am doing wrong here. Please guide me with it.

Comment: Perhaps your project has http interceptors that are capturing and manipulating the error reponse.

Comment: JC Fotd: Its working for other status code like 404. Just for 503, status is coming as -1.

Comment: There still could be HTTP interceptors involved. Do a global search in your project for keyword `interceptors` to be sure. Also, this might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312703/whenever-a-cors-http-request-fails-the-response-returned-is-always-0