# Angular 1.5 Response status returning NULL (-1) instead of 503 due to cors

Tags: angularjs, http, access-control, http-status-code-503

I am getting response status of `503` on a `No Access-Control-Allow-Origin`  header error in the browser but `Angular 1.5.5`. `$http` is getting a status of `NULL` (-1). Is there any way for me to get the actual `503` error in `Angular`? Thanks.

Comment: This may help -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312703/whenever-a-cors-http-request-fails-the-response-returned-is-always-0?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score -1):

please add it(Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *) to browser from the browser store (App) section,
then check it again...
Thanks.

Comment: Hi thanks, yes I did that but if I do not want to use the browser extension, is there a way to get the status code?

Comment: Hi!
please read about "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin" so you may get answer of it. And till not get any other solution of it, if get, definitely will inform you.