# Angular Error In FireFox When Changing Urls

Tags: angularjs

I have a function in an angular factory that gets invoked when my page is loaded. There's a controller which invokes this factory method.

Looks something that looks like this.

```
factory.getData = $http.post('/LocationOfData/Here').
    then(function(response) {
        // stuff happens here when successful
    }, function (response) {
        console.log('an error has occurred');
   });
```

I noticed that my page works correctly as in `//stuff happens here when successful` gets hit... but only when the page fully loads.

If I load my page and then very quickly click on a link taking me to a different page within my app, an error occurs. (as in the console.log.)

This only seems to happen in FireFox. everything works ok in Chrome.

Any suggestions on what I should change or look out for?

EDIT: The response Object is

`Object { data: null, status: 0, headers: headersGetter/<(), config: Object, statusText: "" }`

Comment: So what does `response` contain when the error occurs?

Comment: can you post the actual error response

Comment: @princeG  posted the response Object

Comment: `status: 0` is a bit odd. Can you see the failed request in your browser's *Network* console? What do the response and response headers look like?

Comment: Are you using any third party routing service (like `ui-router`)? Also, `headersGetter` seems like a good starting point (https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=headersGetter)

Comment: @steve I see a reference to ngRoute

Comment: @Phil There does not seem to be any failed requests in Firefox's network console.

Comment: this might be related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506165/angularjs-http-returns-status-code-0-from-failed-cors-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally in JavaScript while when the page is loading if you are injecting any scripts it will consider it as one of the parallel process,if you disabled the cache of the browser it will not consider the parallel process and it will kill the process,in your case while the page load you are doing a service call and the call will be treated as a separate thread or process in chrome if you are not disabled the cache,you may get the service to fail in Chrome as well if you disabled the cache

Its an assumption only,may help:)